# How to NOT load Solaris SPARC drivers at boot

Tags: boot, drivers, solaris, sparc

Trying to get a driver (one of ours) working on Solaris 10 / 11 (this box happens to be Sol 10), with dev studio 12.3.  It seems to be built, however, it crashes when loading, thanks to a NULL pointer dereference and the box now endlessly reboots.

I found a way to get the ok prompt on my PC keyboard (hold Shift-Break) but I cannot seem to find a way to boot the box and not load the drivers! Single-user mode loads them too!

Do I have to reinstall the OS or is there a keyboard-warrior way out of this?

Comment: Try `boot -a` and when prompted for `/etc/system` filename enter `/dev/null`.

Comment: @steve That's definitely worth a try since it's fast and easy, but unless the driver is only being loaded via `/etc/system` in the first place via something like `forceload`, the driver is still likely to get loaded by default means.

Comment: I tried entering /dev/null for the name of the system file and it loaded the drivers anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried booting off a CD/DVD and mounting the root drive to remove your disable/drivers?

And since you mention Solaris 10, have you tried booting to another ABE (alternate boot environment) if your using LU (Live Upgrade)?  Which would also allow you to mount the primary BE (Boot Environment) and disable/remove your drivers.

You could also try to see if there are any defined on the boot device at the ok prompt with:
`boot <device> -L`
In case of success, it prints the bootable BE's on the device -- memory says also syntax on how to boot to one.

Comment: I have not, but I just asked around and located the sparc solaris 10 dvd.  I don't understand the acronyms in your second para. Could you give me a quick guide or link on how to use the dvd to do this?  I've done it in the past with linux, but solaris is really new to me.

Comment: I edited the response above to spell out the acronyms, as well as adding a command to see if there are any ABEs on the boot device.
There are numerous docs/blogs showing how to use live upgrade as well as booting off a dvd.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `exclude` line to a copy of `/etc/system`, then use that to boot.

Per [the `system.4` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5174/system-4.html#scrolltoc):

> `exclude`: *<namespace>/<modulename>*
>
> Do not allow the listed loadable kernel module to be loaded. `exclude` commands are cumulative; the list of modules to `exclude` is
>   created by combining every `exclude` entry in the `system` file.

You should probably create a failsafe `/etc/system` file when working with kernel modules.

See [**SPARC: How to Boot a System Interactively**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E29492/hbsparcboot-9.html#hbsparcboot-66353) for the full process, including an alternate kernel.  That's probably overkill for your needs.

This should work:

1. Boot via CD/DVD
2. Mount the root filesystem
3. Make a copy of `/etc/system`:
   `cp /a/etc/system /a/etc/system.failsafe`
4. Add `exclude: your/driver` to the failsafe copy.
5. Boot interactively:  `boot -a`
6. When prompted for `/etc/system`, enter `/etc/system.failsafe`.

Comment: I popped in both DVDs and tried to boot via 'boot cdrom -s'.  Both fail with "Can't open boot device".

Comment: @Jon Does `boot cdrom -s` even try to access the CD/DVD?  In other words, to you see the CD/DVD light flashing and/or hear the access?

Comment: The drive has no lights on it. It's just a slot with the eject button underneath. I saw no other lights blink on the front of the box.

Comment: Perhaps the device alias for the cdrom is invalid?  At the ok prompt `devalias`.   I see you added the SPARC tag, which server model is it?